# iterating over dictionaries and returning the corresponding string

Tags: python

Here is the problem:

```
morsecode = {'a':".-", 'b':"-...", 'c':"-.-.", 'd':"-..", \
'e':".", 'f':"..-.", 'g':"--.", 'h':"....", 'i':"..", \
'j':".---", 'k':"-.-", 'l':".-..", 'm':"--", \
'n':"-.", 'o':"---", 'p':".--.", 'q':"--.-", \
'r':".-.", 's':"...", 't':"-", 'u':"..-", 'v':"...-", \
'w':".--", 'x':"-..-", 'y':"-.--", 'z':"--.."}


def morse(mystring):
    output=""

    for key, code in morsecode.items():
        for item in mystring:
            if key==item:
                output+=code

    return output
```

I want to get something like this:

```
>>> morse("a boy")
```

'.-   -... --- -.--'

Yet I can only get :

```
>>> morse("a boy")
```

'-.---....- ---'

The result is the same even though I type "yob a"

Answer (score 9):

You can use `join` and a generator expression

```
def morse(s):
    return ''.join(morsecode.get(i, i) for i in s)
```

This will replace all of the letters, but will preserve the space characters.

**Details**

[`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) takes a sequence of `str` and concatenates them into a single string.

The syntax `(something for something in sequence)` is called a "[generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)". It is a compact 1-line equivalent to a `for` loop. You should also research "list comprehension" as this is a very similar technique, but creates a list instead of a generator.

[`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) is a safer alternative to lookup a key from a `dict` than `[]`, because it will not throw an exception if that key doesn't exist. It will either return `None`, or the second argument you pass in.

Comment: for using .get() instead of [key] indexing +1

Comment: @MalikBrahimi That will handle specifically spaces, I basically left any character in there that is not in the dictionary, so it will handle spaces, newlines, etc

Comment: @CoryKramer: it's great that you don't recreate string objects over and over again, in contrast to other answers. You got my upvote for that.

Comment: I'm not familiar to this kind of code(I'm still a beginner), can you explain it a bit more or simply provide me a link for research?

Comment: @christinang I tried to break down what that line was doing in more detail. Hopefully that provides you enough documentation and other breadcrumbs to look into any of those operations in further detail.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterarte over the input string and then append the corresponding value for the key (char) to an  variable (`f` in the below example).

```
def morse(s):
    morsecode = {'a':".-", 'b':"-...", 'c':"-.-.", 'd':"-..", \
    'e':".", 'f':"..-.", 'g':"--.", 'h':"....", 'i':"..", \
    'j':".---", 'k':"-.-", 'l':".-..", 'm':"--", \
    'n':"-.", 'o':"---", 'p':".--.", 'q':"--.-", \
     'r':".-.", 's':"...", 't':"-", 'u':"..-", 'v':"...-", \
     'w':".--", 'x':"-..-", 'y':"-.--", 'z':"--.."}

    f = ""
    for i in s:
        if not i == ' ':
            f += morsecode[i]
        else:
            f += ' '

    return f
```

Comment: Your function won't work against an input with spaces (take `a boy` for example)

Comment: Or just add a space key to the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are iterating over the dictionary first, so you are adding conversions for whatever you are finding inside the string into the output variable , which is not in the correct order.

You can try -

```
morsecode = {'a':".-", 'b':"-...", 'c':"-.-.", 'd':"-..", \
'e':".", 'f':"..-.", 'g':"--.", 'h':"....", 'i':"..", \
'j':".---", 'k':"-.-", 'l':".-..", 'm':"--", \
'n':"-.", 'o':"---", 'p':".--.", 'q':"--.-", \
'r':".-.", 's':"...", 't':"-", 'u':"..-", 'v':"...-", \
'w':".--", 'x':"-..-", 'y':"-.--", 'z':"--.."}

def morse(s):
    outputs = ''
    for item in s:
            outputs += morsecode.get(item,item)
    return outputs
```

Comment: I've put 'for item in string' above 'for key, code in morsecode.items()', now it works.

Comment: But why does the order of iteration matters?

Comment: because, lets say we are changing `a` with `1` and `b` with `2` , for example - , and we want to change the complete string `ababab` , so we first take `a` from the dictionary , and then for each `a` element in the dictionary, we add its translation `1` to the output string (this is what you are doing) , so we get - `111` . Now do same with `b` and at end we get - `111222` . Do you see the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
morsecode = {'a':".-", 'b':"-...", 'c':"-.-.", 'd':"-..", \
'e':".", 'f':"..-.", 'g':"--.", 'h':"....", 'i':"..", \
'j':".---", 'k':"-.-", 'l':".-..", 'm':"--", \
'n':"-.", 'o':"---", 'p':".--.", 'q':"--.-", \
'r':".-.", 's':"...", 't':"-", 'u':"..-", 'v':"...-", \
'w':".--", 'x':"-..-", 'y':"-.--", 'z':"--.."}


def morse(mystring):
    output=""
    for item in mystring:
        if item in morsecode.keys():
            output+=morsecode[item]
    return output
```